# Unity get distance to edge of Collider2D from within

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a [Collider2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) which moves around within a larger, stationary Collider2D and I'd like to get the distance from the centre of the smaller one to the edge of the larger one along the direction it's travelling in.

My first thought was to use a [Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) such as:

```
Physics2D.Raycast(this.transform.position, 
                  this.rigidbody2D.velocity.normalized).distance;
```

But obviously the distance is always 0 as they are already intersecting.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: Here is a diagram as requested
[image: diagram]

Both circles are Collider2D objects, the arrow is the direction the smaller one is travelling in and the red x is the point I'd like to find (so I can determine the distance).

Comment: Use the bounds of the collider... http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-bounds.html

Comment: A diagram or screenshot would be very helpful, I'm not sure exactly what you're describing when you say one collider is inside the other.

Comment: Good idea Savlon however the Bounds represent an axis aligned bounding box, whereas the outer Collider2D is a circle.

Comment: I've managed to do it by writing my own ray-circle intersection test, but I'd still be interested to know if there was a way of doing it built into Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to check for a collision you could do it mathematically.

If you know the radius/position of the circle, the position of the smaller Collider2D, and the vector of its movement, then you can solve where that movement vector intersects with the circle.

Here is how to figure that out mathematically:
http://www.analyzemath.com/CircleEq/circle_line_intersection.html

Another approach if you still want to raycast could be to cast the ray from a point along the smaller object's movement vector with distance greater than the larger circle's diameter. This ray would then be cast toward the smaller object. Essentially, you are casting the ray from outside the circle instead of inside the circle.